# Unable to add to Map

Tags: java, tree, adjacency-list

It seems to be getting a `NullPointerException` in thread main, specifically on the line where I put the nodes and where I call the `addEdge` method.

```
private TreeMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodeToNeighbours;
```

**In main**

```
Graph test1 = new Graph();
Node n1 = new Node(1); 
Node n2 = new Node(2); 
test1.addEdges(n1, n2);
```

**addEdges Class**

```
public void addEdge(Node node1, Node node2) {

    nodeToNeighbours.put(node2, new TreeSet<Node>());
    nodeToNeighbours.put(node1, new TreeSet<Node>());
}
```

Comment: you need to initialize `nodeToNeighbors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just declaring the map and not initialising it here:

```
private TreeMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodeToNeighbours;
```

so `nodeToNeighbours` is null and hence trying to add something to it causes `NullPointerException`. You can initialise this as mentioned here:

```
nodeToNeighbours = new TreeMap<Node, Set<Node>>();
```

If you are using Java 7 or above , then just like this:

```
nodeToNeighbours = new TreeMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just declare it not initializes it

```
private TreeMap<Node, Set<Node>> nodeToNeighbours;
```

As default every reference initializes with `null` hence you are getting `NullPointerException`. Try initializing it as

```
nodeToNeighbours = new TreeMap<Node, Set<Node>>();
```

Comment: this is incorrect "As default every reference initializes with null". By default class attributes are initialled to their default values, for objects it is null for primitives it is not.

Comment: Here the class atrribute is `nodeToNeighbours` and is a `class-type` that's why it is default is `null`